# Issues attempting to display variable containing collections using Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

### Premise:

I'm playing around with knockout and have been trying to display a populated array variable through and html table.

### Problem:

The problem is that I don't know how to display the  "last_name" property in the variable array shown below.

JSON FILE + HTML FILE:

```
 //JSON FILE
 $(function() 
 {
    console.log('Ready');

    ko.applyBindings(new myvm());
 }

 function myvm() 
 {
     var self = this;
     //cust contains the data mentioned at the bottom
     self.customers = cust;
 }

//HTML FILE
<table class= "table" id="kocustomertable" border= "1">
    <tr> 
        <th>Last name</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tbody data-bind = 'customers'> 
        <tr>
            <td data-bind = 'text: last_name'></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### SAMPLE CONTENT OF DATA INSIDE VARIABLE "CUST"

```
[
  {"id":1,"first_name":"Tracey","last_name":"Jansson","email":"tjansson0@discuz.net","gender":"Female","ip_address":"167.88.183.95","birthdate":"1999-08-25T17:24:23Z","website":"http://hello.com","city":"Medellín","credits":7471}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `data-bind` on your `<tbody>` is missing a binding.

Your have referenced the your view model `customers` property in your HTML but you haven't told knockout how to bind it to the view. If you add a `foreach` binding, you should see that you get a table row per customer. For example, you could replace your opening `<tbody>` with:

```
<tbody data-bind='foreach: customers'>
```

Hope this helps. Take a look at the [knockout documentation on foreach](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html) for more info.